# Group by Month and Perform Cumulative Sum of Unique Values

Tags: python, pandas

Below is a simplified version of the df in question:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2021-01-01','2021-01-02','2021-01-03','2021-01-04','2021-02-01','2021-02-02','2021-02-03','2021-02-04'],
                   'month':  ['Jan','Jan','Jan','Jan','Feb','Feb','Feb','Feb'],
                   'label':  ['A','A','B','A','A','B', 'C', 'A']})

df

     date       month  label
0   2021-01-01   Jan     A
1   2021-01-02   Jan     A
2   2021-01-03   Jan     B
3   2021-01-04   Jan     A
4   2021-02-01   Feb     A
5   2021-02-02   Feb     B
6   2021-02-03   Feb     C
7   2021-02-04   Feb     A
```

I would like to have a new column showing the cumulative sum of unique *labels* on a monthly basis.

Intended df:

```
    date       month    label   count
0   2021-01-01  Jan       A       1
1   2021-01-02  Jan       A       1
2   2021-01-03  Jan       B       2
3   2021-01-04  Jan       A       2
4   2021-02-01  Feb       A       1
5   2021-02-02  Feb       B       2
6   2021-02-03  Feb       C       3
7   2021-02-04  Feb       A       3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use sort to check by `month` and `label` to check for differences in rows with `shift`. Join this boolean array to our dataframe and use `groupby.cumsum` to get the counter:

```
d = df.sort_values(["month", "label"])
s = d["label"].ne(d["label"].shift()).rename("count")
df = df.join(s)

df["count"] = df.groupby("month")["count"].cumsum()
```

```
        date month label  count
0 2021-01-01   Jan     A      1
1 2021-01-02   Jan     A      1
2 2021-01-03   Jan     B      2
3 2021-01-04   Jan     A      2
4 2021-02-01   Feb     A      1
5 2021-02-02   Feb     B      2
6 2021-02-03   Feb     C      3
7 2021-02-04   Feb     A      3
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

We can make use of a cumulative sum of booleans:, by checking if the previous `label` is equal to the current. Then groupby and cumsum

```
s = df["label"].ne(df["label"].shift())
df["count"] = s.groupby(df["month"]).cumsum()
```

```
        date month label  count
0 2021-01-01   Jan     A      1
1 2021-01-01   Jan     A      1
2 2021-01-03   Jan     B      2
3 2021-02-01   Feb     A      1
4 2021-02-02   Feb     B      2
5 2021-02-03   Feb     C      3
```

---

Or more safe and make use of your dates by doing a groupby on year-month:

```
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

s = df["label"].ne(df["label"].shift())
df["count"] = s.groupby(df["date"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m")).cumsum()
```

```
        date month label  count
0 2021-01-01   Jan     A      1
1 2021-01-01   Jan     A      1
2 2021-01-03   Jan     B      2
3 2021-02-01   Feb     A      1
4 2021-02-02   Feb     B      2
5 2021-02-03   Feb     C      3
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your contribution, unfortunately this is a simplified version of the df in question and the labels are not ordered in a way to make this solution feasible.

Comment: @LeoGER so that means your example is wrong right? Can you update it

Comment: Sorry, my original example was wrong. I have amended it now.

Comment: No problem. Added new answer.